# How to make a loop execute with a callback value of a function within

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb

I am trying to update couchdb multiple times, each time the `_rev` changes. So i need to wait till i get callback from firs update. But the Node.js Loop seems to be iterating before i am getting the callback. Here is my code

```
function upload(req, res, next) {
if ('POST' !== req.method) return next();
rev = req.param('rev');
idAndRevData = {
        id : "some_doc_id",
        rev : rev
       };
for (x in array){
   var item = array[x];
   db.saveAttachment(idAndRevData, attachmentData, function (err, reply) {
      if (err) {
         console.dir(err)
         return
       } 
       idAndRevData.rev = reply.rev;
       callback("done");
   });
 }
}
```

I tried using `async.each` that also did not seem working

```
    async.each(array,fileupload,function(err){
       if(err)thorw err;
       console.log("done")
    });
```

Here i am able to get "done" printed as many as the length of the `array` but the code inside `fileupload` was not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about like that:

```
function upload(req, res, next) {
    if ('POST' !== req.method) return next();
    rev = req.param('rev');
    idAndRevData = {
        id : "some_doc_id",
        rev : rev
    };

    var processData = function() {
        if(array.length == 0) {
            callback("done");
            return;
        }
        var item = array.shift();
        db.saveAttachment(idAndRevData, attachmentData, function (err, reply) {
            if (err) {
                console.dir(err)
                return
            } 
            idAndRevData.rev = reply.rev;
            processData();
        });
    }
}
```

So, the idea is to fetch the elements of the array one by one, only when the db callback is called.

Comment: My bad. In the question i posted pseudo code. It seems that array is a js Object and `shift` will not work.

Comment: Ok, then post the structure of the array object.

Comment: i created an array from the JS object. Now it seems working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`async.each` executes the iterator parallely, so use `async.eachSeries`. This would ensure that the request executes succesively, next is only called when current one is finished.

Comment: i dont know what what is wrong. this is how i call `async.eachSeries`
`async.eachSeries(req.files,square, function(err){
if(err) throw err;
console.log("done");
});`
and my `square` function is 
<br>
`var square = function (num, doneCallback) {`
 `console.lod("num");`
  `return doneCallback(null);`
`};`